# efficient way to get the max of each row for large sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix and I want to get the maximum value for each row. In numpy, I can call numpy.max(mat, axis=1), but I can not find similar function for scipy sparse matrix.  Is there any efficient way to get the max of each row for a large sparse matrix?

Answer (score 4):

If your matrix, lets call it `a`, is stored in CSR format, then `a.data` has all the non-zero entries ordered by rows, and `a.indptr` has the index of the first element of every row. You can use this to calculate what you are after as follows:

```
def sparse_max_row(csr_mat):
    ret = np.maximum.reduceat(csr_mat.data, csr_mat.indptr[:-1])
    ret[np.diff(csr_mat.indptr) == 0] = 0
    return ret
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this same problem. Jaime's solution breaks if any of the rows in the matrix are completely empty. Here's a workaround:

```
def sparse_max_row(csr_mat):
    ret = np.zeros(csr_mat.shape[0])
    ret[np.diff(csr_mat.indptr) != 0] = np.maximum.reduceat(csr_mat.data,csr_mat.indptr[:-1][np.diff(csr_mat.indptr)>0])
    return ret
```

Comment: This fails when none of the data entries are greater than 0:
https://gist.github.com/jni/6120922#file-example-py